# How do I perform a $geoIntersects query with Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, sinatra, mongoid, geospatial

I'm using Sinatra and **mongoid** driver, now I'm trying to perform this query in mongoid, actually I have a geospatial (Polygon) field called '**geometry**':

```
db.states.find({
    geometry: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [-99.176524, 18.929204]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Actually this query works in mongodb shell.

However, I want to find states that intersects with given point (Point-in-polygon) with mongoid or maybe other ruby driver.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking at doing the same thing. From what I could see, this isn't supported in Mongoid yet, and I don't know what the timeframe is in terms of it being implemented.

In the meantime, you can use the Mongoid/Moped driver to run the query, but you won't get any of the object mapping niceness that Mongoid provides - you'll just get arrays/hashes back. Example syntax below:

```
ids = Mongoid.default_session["states"].find( geometry:
    { "$geoIntersects" =>
        { "$geometry" =>
            { type: "Point", coordinates: [-99.176524, 18.929204] }
        }
    }
).select( id: 1 )
```

This actually returns an array of hashes with a key "_id" and the value of the _id field, but you could configure this as you wish.

Comment: According to Durran, support for $geoIntersects will be in the Mongoid 4.0 release.

Comment: 4.0 is released but I don't see `$geoIntersects` in changelog :( https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: or not released? :) I see 4.0 in changelog but 4.0 isn't available for downloading

Answer (score 5):

I was recently searching for this, and after a while I found the following. Maybe someone else will have use for this..

$geoIntersects is now implemented in mongoid 4.0.0.beta1, but not well documented.. I found this in the origin changelog: https://github.com/mongoid/origin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-1

```ruby
query.geo_spacial(:location.intersects_line => [[ 1, 10 ], [ 2, 10 ]])
query.geo_spacial(:location.intersects_point => [[ 1, 10 ]])
query.geo_spacial(:location.intersects_polygon => [[ 1, 10 ], [ 2, 10 ], [ 1, 10 ]])
query.geo_spacial(:location.within_polygon => [[ 1, 10 ], [ 2, 10 ], [ 1, 10 ]])
```

and a commit: https://github.com/mongoid/origin/commit/30938fad644f17fe38f62cf90571b78783b900d8

```ruby
 # Add a $geoIntersects selection. Symbol operators must be used as shown in
 # the examples to expand the criteria.
 #
 # @note The only valid geometry shapes for a $geoIntersects are: :line,
 #   :point, and :polygon.
 # ...
 # @example Add a geo intersect criterion for a point.
 #   query.geo_intersects(:location.point => [[ 1, 10 ]])
```

In my project i have mongoid (4.0.0.beta1) and origin (2.1.0)
I have a model Polygon

```ruby
class Polygon
  include Mongoid::Document
  # some fields 

  embeds_many :loc

  # coordinates is an array of two points: [10, 12]
  def find_polygons_with_point(coordinates)
    # This is where the magic happens!
    Polygon.all.geo_spacial(:loc.intersects_point => coordinates)
  end

end
```

And a model Loc

```ruby
class Loc
  field :type, type: String #Need to be set to 'Polygon' when creating a new location.
  field :coordinates, type: Array
  # For some reason the array has to be in the format
  # [ [ [1,1], [2,3], [5,3], [1,1] ] ]
  # And the first coordinate needs to be the same as the last
  # to close the polygon

  embedded_in :polygon

  index({ coordinates: "2d" }, { min: -200, max: 200 }) #may not need min/max
end
```

This code returns all polygons that has this point inside.

There might be more elegant ways of doing this. If so I would like to hear it :)

Comment: The reason for the format is it uses GeoJSON. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#polygon

Answer (score 1):

While we are waiting for Mongoid 4.0 with added **$geoIntersects** support, I added it by myself. It allows chaining and all other cool things. Find this file (your path may look a bit different):

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/origin-1.1.0/lib/origin/selectable.rb
```

Add this anywhere in the file:

```
def geo_intersects(criterion = nil)
   __override__(criterion, "$geoIntersects")
end
key :geo_intersects, :override, "$geoIntersects"
```

Now you can do:

```
Houses.where(:color => "red").geo_intersects(:loc => {"$geometry" => {:type => "Polygon", :coordinates => [[[1,2],[2,3][1,2]]]})
```

Comment: I created a fork [here](https://github.com/GovSciences/origin/tree/geo_intersects) that adds that functionality. You can use it in your Gemfile like `gem 'origin', git: "https://github.com/GovSciences/origin.git", branch: "geo_intersects"`