# Find if given longitude, latitude pair lies in any of the polygon in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, analytics, geospatial

As per my current understanding on MongoDB we search our collection by passing an array of [long, lat] pair arrays, to check if that document's [long, lat] pair exits inside the coordinates `[[ [], [], [] ]]`.

i,e.,

```
db.SomeCollection.find({
    "location":{
        $geoWithin: {
            $geometry: { 
                type: "Polygon", 
                coordinates: [
                    [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]],
                    [[2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7]]
                ] }
        }
    }
})
```

What i am looking for is that i need to feed the [long, lat] pair to a document containing fixed Polygonal Geofence arrays and conclude if the [long, lat] pair exists inside any of those [Polygonal Geofence arrays].

Is this possible in MongoDB? Is my question valid?

> Please Note: I am novice to MongoDB as well as Geospatial Data hence
>   forgive if the question contains wrong terminologies.

Comment: I think this article contains what you are looking for: http://robgillen.com/technology/2016/09/03/geofences-in-mongodb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days I am returning to my question as i found the answer to it.

The solution is posted in [here by Jacob Ribnik](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/bLJg4FFpQ04).

hence implementing it to my problem it would be something like below:

```
db.Poly_Geofence_collection.find(
{
    "location": {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [1,1]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Where my `Poly_Geofence_collection` collection looks like:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("SomeRandom12ByteObjectId"),
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "name" : "Location Name",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [0, 0], [1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [0, 0]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```